# how to define methods for change in position of car in a car class

Tags: c++, class

Create a class named  “Car” with attributes xPosition, yPosition, speed . The class should have  methods  such as “accelerate”, “decelerate” to increment and decrement the speed of the car while for change in xPosition & yPosition, there should be methods such as turn Left, turnRight. A n extra method “currState” should display all the data members of the object

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;
class Car {
private:
    float xPosition, yPosition, speed;
public:
    Car(float ,float ,float);
    float accelarate();
    float deaccelarate();
    void turnLeft();
    void turnRight();
    void currState();
}
Car::Car(float x,float y,float sp) {
    xPosition=x;
    yPosition=y;
    speed=sp;
}

float Car::accelarate() { 
    ++speed;
    return speed;
}

float Car::deaccelarate() {
    --speed;
    return speed;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can edit your question and insert your code so we can have a look at it and find out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't know how to define turnLeft and turnRight functions
#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;

class Car
{
 private:
  float xPosition, yPosition, speed;
 public:
     Car(float ,float ,float);
     float accelarate();
     float deaccelarate();
     void turnLeft();
     void turnRight();
     void currState();
}

Car::Car(float x,float y,float sp)
{
 xPosition=x;
 yPosition=y;
 speed=sp;
 
}

float Car::accelarate()
{
 ++speed;
 return speed;
}

float Car::deaccelarate()
{
 --speed;
 return speed;
}

Comment: Before you can implement `turnLeft` and `turnRight`, you have to determine what they are supposed to do. How are they affecting the car's position and speed? Perhaps turning a car left or right changes the direction where the car is going, so perhaps you need to model that somehow. You have `xPosition` and `yPosition`, so maybe you also need `xSpeed` and `ySpeed`.

Comment: No I need to just change the direction in a 2D plane

Comment: But you don't have any direction, you only have `xPosition`, `yPosition` and `speed`. How do you know in which direction the car is driving?

Comment: @Blaze it's my assignment task I can't use extra methods or attributes because I'll get negative marks for that

Comment: Your assignment task is to change a direction that doesn't exist?

Comment: What I'm supposed to say when I'm already confused with what they're asking me to do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this may help:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;
class Car {
private:
    float xPosition, yPosition, speed;
public:
    Car(float ,float ,float);
    float accelarate();
    float deaccelarate();
    void turnLeft();
    void turnRight();
    void currState();
}
Car::Car(float x,float y,float sp) {
    xPosition=x;
    yPosition=y;
    speed=sp;
}

void Car::accelarate() { 
    ++speed;
}

void Car::deaccelarate() {
    --speed;

} 
void Car::moveX(int a)
{
    xPosition=xPosition+a
}
void Car::turnLeft(){
  moveX(-1)
}
void Car::turnRight(){
  moveX(1)
}
```

For currState I guess is

```
void Car::currState(){
std::cout << "I am in " << xPosition << " and " << yPosition << " with velocity " << speed << std::endl;
}
```